# How to fill null field from another table in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have select query and resultind dataset like below;

**Query**:  `select op_id, op_name, emp_id from employee where ....`

**Resulting dataset**:

```
OP_ID      | OP_NAME      | EMP_ID
-----        -------        ------
1234       | NULL         |  1
2345       | fgdf         |  2
3456       | sdfsasd      |  3
4567       | NULL         |  2
1234       | xcxc         |  3
2345       | sfsfs        |  4
```

My purpose is to get null values of above select statement from another table that contains `op_name` that equals `emp_name`.

```
EMP_ID  | EMP_NAME
------    -------- 
1       | asdasd
2       | ASDFG
3       | SDFSSD
4       | SDFSF
```

What should my select query be?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is the name of the other table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
select e.op_id
,      nvl(e.op_name, o.emp_name) op_name
,      e.emp_id 
from   employee e
,      other_employee_table o
where  e.emp_id = o.emp_id
and    ...
```